# Windows Mobile 6 Application from WindowsCE

Tags: java, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I have a game written in java working on windows CE now I would like to upgrade to windows mobile 6.x. what are the things I need to change/do?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on your JVM. I recently ported a Java app from Win CE 5 to 6, I only had to hide the virtual keyboard using an api call. You should just "try" it on some devices. Your JVM may have a changelog providing more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need either the WinMo version of the exact same JVM you were using in Windows CE or you need to port your application to a JVM that is supported on WinMo.  Without knowing what JVM you're running against we can't offer much more than that.